Older home plumbing not sufficient for newer washing machine
I have an older home with a newer washing machine left by the previous owner. When washing clothes, the newer washing machine drains water at a higher rate than the plumbing was built to handle. Is there any way to slow the rate of water being drained or is the only option to hire a plumber to install better piping?

yes, restrict the flow on the hose with a clamp

Need a lot more info here in order to be most helpful. Photos? New Model? Old model? Age of home? Don’t restrict the machine. That’s asking for more issues with the appliance.

Is the plumbing small diameter?  Have you checked for partial clog?  Older home gives time for stuff to build up in the pipes, reducing the inside diameter of the pipes.

Is the waste pipe abs/ galvanized steel/ other? If abs or other plastic, you should be able to have it cleared and get enough flow. If galvanized, you might be looking at a re-pipe. (And a re-pipe might be a good thing generally, for all kinds of reasons. A quick google will show you what galvy pipes look like on the inside.)


allow the machine to empty into a large bucket then drain that...

sort the plumbing drain - will cause fewer issues


I prefer 2 as it also allows future changes.
BTW constricting the machine waste pipe can cause errors and stop the machine.

The classic version of #1 was to have the machine drain onto a slop sink. But figuring out the drain problem is probably a better answer.

If it's an older home, I suspect a laundry sink will be less work than upgrading the plumbing.

We have a laundry sink and it works great for this exact purpose.
